# Spring batch: Listener Scheduler scenario

Tags: spring, listener, spring-batch, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

I am new to Spring Batch and I thought Spring Batch will be useful in my project.
The scenario is as follows :
I want to implement a scheduler which will continuously listen to a mysql/oracle database table. Once a new record is inserted into the database table, depending upon one of the column value of my database table, a new thread will be spawned correspondingly in my scheduler which will run periodically.

Any idea how can this be implemented ?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our application we implement event-driven solution for this instead of continuously listening to a database table.

With that approach you need to create a message queue and put a message on it every time the table is updated.

And then define a listener that will process that update event and for instance run Spring Batch job.

Comment: thank you for the response. I will try this option too.